# IsAuthenticated not working as a function using nodejs with passport-local

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm a begginer with node js and I'm trying to check if the user is authenticated after he registers.

I'm using passport, passport-local and passport-local-mongoose to save the user in a mongoDB database.

This is how the user gets **registered**:

```
app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.register({username: username}, password, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/register");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect("/drive");
      });
    }
  });

});
```

And this is how I'm trying to check **if the user is authenticated**:

```
app.get("/drive", function (req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("drive");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});
```

If I'm using **isAuthenticated()** as a function call, this logic will not work and I'll always get redirected to the login page, if I'm using **isAuthenticated** (not a function call), this logic will work.

I don't understand what is the difference between these two (in the passport package context) and why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this fixed, it was a pretty simple problem.

When I'm declaring my **session** options:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Our little secret.',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {secure: true}
}))
```

I'm using `cookie: {secure: true}`, and since I'm working on a local enviroment with no HTTPS, as soon as I authenticate, I get deauthenticated due to the fact that the cookie that is supposed to be generated can only work under HTTPS.

Solution is to just set the **cookie** option to **false** and call **isAuthenticated()**.